# What is the best way to make a sidebar that can have content scrolling underneath it?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to make a page that is basically this structure:

[image]

What I am trying to do is have the content in the bigger area that is in a scrolling slideshow and have the content scroll to the left underneath the white side bar. It seems simple enough, but I have tried many different structures and not sure the best way to go about this.

I have made a tile and put it in the body and repeat-y, which yields the proper visual result, however I can't get the content wrapper to z-index underneath it. I am trying to get the side bar to be 100% height.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your browser support options, your best bet may be to try [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). While it is still new and relatively unsupported in old browsers, [all the new browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) at least the "legacy" version of it.

The new flexbox spec is supported by Chrome and will be by FF. If you choose to use legacy flexbox, you won't have to worry about your settings colliding with the new spec since they use completely different options.

Whatever you choose, I know that you'll love flexbox! I've used it in my recent projects and it is WAY better than floats :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know I already answered, but if you're looking for a short term solution, you could try tricking your layout into thinking it's a table:

```
#outerwrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
#topbar { 
    display: table-row;
}
#innerwrapper {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
#innerwrapper .leftdiv {
    display: table-cell;
}
#innerwrapper .rightdiv {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Untested, but with some tweaking it should work.

Comment: yes this is more of what I'm looking for, thanks. What would the html structure look like? Just not sure how to integrate the classes of the id's.

Comment: `#outerwrapper > #topbar + #innerwrapper > .leftdiv + .rightdiv`

Comment: that is still unclear. I don't know what you mean ">" and "+". Can you be more specific or forward? <div id="outer wrapper"><div id="top bar">etc... thanks

Comment: `>` is child descendant (like in CSS) and `+` is sibling (like in CSS). [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/cUYUg/)

Comment: thanks for your effort but I found a really simple solution. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 line-height: 1;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-weight:300;
}
.content_wrapper {
 width:960px;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
.side_bar {
 width:250px;
 height:100%;
 background:#efeff0;
 position:fixed; right:0px; top:94px;
}
<div class="content_wrapper clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="side_bar">
</div>
```